# How to save present, absent list of students in database for attendance management system?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to save the present/absent details of students in database everyday. In my project I cant save it. Don't know how to save this .  I am getting the student name and roll number from another table (table name - student). Help me . Thank you in advance

my database table is like is ,(table name -- attendance)

```
+---+----------------+-------------+-----------------------------+
|   |      Name      |    Type     |         Attributes          |
+---+----------------+-------------+-----------------------------+
| 1 | id Primary     | int(50)     | No                          |
| 2 | name           | varchar(20) | No                          |
| 3 | Roll_Number    | varchar(20) | No                          |
| 4 | date           | timestamp   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| 5 | present_absent | varchar(20) | No                          |
+---+----------------+-------------+-----------------------------+
```

My code is class_attendance. php is below

```
<?php
     include("php/connect.php");
     include("php/check.php");

 $res['role']=$_SESSION['role'];

 $hid = $_SESSION['id'];

 $errormsg = '';
 $action = "add";

  $name ='';
  $Roll_Number =''; 
  $present_absent =''; 

 if(isset($_POST['save']))
     {
 $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['id']);
 $sql = "select name,Roll_Number from student  ";


  $sql = $conn->query("INSERT INTO attendance (name,Roll_Number,present_absent)
  VALUES ('$name','$Roll_Number','$present_absent')") ;

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="attendance.php";</script>';

 }



 $action = "add";
     if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="edit" )
 {
   $id = isset($_GET['id'])?mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['id']):'';

  $sqlEdit = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE id='".$id."'");
 if($sqlEdit->num_rows)
  {
   $rowsEdit = $sqlEdit->fetch_assoc();
  extract($rowsEdit);
   $action = "update";
 }
 else
  {
    $_GET['action']="";
  }

}


  if(isset($_REQUEST['act']) && @$_REQUEST['act']=="1")
 {
  $errormsg = "<div class='alert alert-success'> <a href='#' class='close' 
  data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
  <strong>Success!</strong> Student Add successfully</div>";
 }

?>




<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
            Manage Student  
   <? php echo "Today is " . date("m/d/Y") . "";?>
    </div>
<div class="panel-body">
 <div class="table-sorting table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover id="Sortable">
         <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>S.No</th>
                   <th>Roll Number</th>
                   <th>Name</th>
                   <th>Attendance</th>
                </tr>
           </thead>
         <tbody>

<form method="post" action="class_attendance .php" id="attendance_Form">
            <?php if(isset($_GET["id"]))  
 { 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM student as s,branch as b WHERE s.branch=b.id and b.id='".$_GET['id']."' and s.delete_status='0' " ;
        $q = $conn->query($sql);
        $i=1;
        while($r = $q->fetch_assoc())
            {

            echo '<tr >
                     <td>'.$i.'</td>
                     <td>'.$r['Roll_Number'].'</td>
                     <td>'.$r['name'].'</td>
                     <td> 
<select  class="form-control" id="present_absent" name="present_absent">                      
       <option  if ($present_absent == "Present" ) echo "selected" value="Present">Present</option>
       <option  if ($present_absent == "Absent" ) echo "selected"  value="Absent">Absent</option>

                      </select>
                     </td>
                   </tr>';
                $i++;
                        }
 }

                     echo "</table>";
                            ?>
                     <button type="submit" name="save" >Save </button>
            </form>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

This is how I save the attendance: [image: this is how I save the attendance]

When I submit the attendance, students name and their present absent list should be saved every day with respective date.

Comment: There are quite a few problems with your database design. First off: name - what if you have multiple Fred Smiths enrolled. Which one will the system pick? It is best to have a foreign key pointing back to the studentID (or some other uniquie number for the student). Secondly, the present_absent field only needs to be a char(1). This will allow you to have specific codes for attendance/non-attendance. Makes life easier when creating/searching for information. Thirdly, you id should also be an auto-increment.

Comment: this code is a bit of a shambles, I can't really work out what's going on.  you set ````$add```` twice, you assign ````$sql```` to a select statement then immediately overwrite it to a query object.  I'm not sure why you are echoing out a javascript redirect?  You are also passing variables straight in so you are at a huge risk of SQL injection, but also I can't see where any of these,````$name ='';
  $Roll_Number =''; 
  $present_absent ='';```` get set?
I think the first step would be to re-organise your code

Comment: Can you explain why **exactly** you cannot save that data in your system? What's the exact problem with all that code, besides the mixup between HTML and PHP which you should definitely avoid

Comment: also these include parts don't look right ````include("php/connect .php");
     include("php/check .php");````

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution should work if you correct a few issues:

Change

```
<form method="post" action="class_attendance .php" id="attendance_Form">
```

to

```
<form method="post" action="class_attendance.php" id="attendance_Form">
```

Also, $present_absent is not yet defined in your select tag logic in your form, I would suggest adding a placeholder and removing PHP logic from the option tags.